# Network tab in chrome dev tools stops recording requests

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm experiencing an issue that has only started occurring in the last month or so.  The http request log in the network tab stops recording requests after the initial page load.  I get how this behaviour might be desired in some circumstances, but in my case it's not very useful.  I'm making several http requests after the initial page load, and unless I remember to hit record I won't see anything in the log.

Is this a problem others are having?  Is there a setting buried away somewhere that can rectify this?

Comment: Can you go to `chrome://version` and get the version of Chrome you are using please? Looks like a bug if it is stopping after initial load. Recording should record until manually stopped. Canary currently is working properly as it always has.

Comment: Current version of my browser is 46.0.2490.86m.  But isn't everyone on the same version now that Chrome is evergreen?

Comment: Just checking which version I need to test with. There are multiple branches, Stable, Beta, Dev, Canary. Sometimes people switch and forget. You are running the latest Stable for desktops. Just pulled up a copy and tested the same, mine is not stopping. Is this happening on every site for you or some specific ones?

Comment: It's happening with all sites.   I'll start disabling extensions to see if one of them are responsible.

Comment: With all extensions disabled the problem persists.

Comment: Then please download Chrome Canary and test with that. If the problem still exists, file a bug at http://crbug.com/new . If it works as expected in Canary, then you will sadly just need to wait for the next stable update that contains the fix to be published.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem, make sure that the "Capture screenshots" feature (camera icon) is disabled in Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: This did the trick.  However I logged a ticket with chrome as I would still consider this to be a bug.  I can't imagine this is an intentional feature.

Comment: Really annoying that they suddenly decide to just turn off network requests capture and turn on screenshots instead. Although appreciate upgrades they should learn to not mess with current settings.

Comment: @abyrne85 If you still can, will you please find and post a link to the ticket? I'd like to check the status

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. There's a simple solution.

Go to Developer tools **Settings** > **Preferences** and then tap on <kbd>Restore defaults and reload</kbd>.